# Mui LinearProgress Bar stops displaying on display flex

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, progress-bar

I'am trying to make a custom bullet graph with material UI, my idea is 2 MuiLinearProgress bar next to each other with a vertical Divider in between. I can't seem to find a way to display them next to each other.

```
<div className={classes.bulletGraph}>
  <div>
   <LinearProgress
    className={classes.firstBar}
    value={80}
    variant="determinate"
    title="test"
   />
  </div>
  <div>
   <LinearProgress
    className={classes.secondBar}
    value={0}
    variant="determinate"
   />
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using display flex on the parent but it makes them disappear, I also tried inline block and I got the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your `<LinearProgress>` with [`<Grid>`](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) component.

```
<Grid spacing={1} container>
    <Grid xs item>
        <LinearProgress value={80} variant="determinate" title="test" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid xs item>
        <LinearProgress color="secondary" value={0} variant="determinate" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Live demo

[image: Edit romantic-sun-dt6ie]

You can set different [spacing](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing) and [ratios](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#fluid-grids) beetween items.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the LinearProgress component working with Flexbox as follows:

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
 <LinearProgress
  value={80}
  variant="determinate"
  title="test"
  style={{ width: "100%", marginRight: "4px" }}
 />
 <LinearProgress
  color="secondary"
  value={0}
  variant="determinate"
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
 />
</div>
```

Setting the width to 100% fixes the issue with this component disappearing when used with Flexbox. Note that I'd typically put these styles in a CSS file, but put them in a style property here to keep this snippet simple.

You can see this working here:

[image: Edit mui-linearprogress-bar-stops-displaying-on-display-flex-f5eqi0]

Answer (score 0):

you can just add flex-grow to each LinearProgress when the parent has display flex:

```js
sx={{flexGrow:1}}
```